# How do I get a description of the current OS version in windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, version

I need to get a simple description of the OS, such as "Windows XP (SP2)" or "Windows 2000 Professional" to include in some debugging code. Ideally, I'd like to simply retrieve it by calling a "GetOSDisplayName" function.

Is there such a function available for C++ win32 programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Was hoping for a built-in function, but I guess this is the best there is. :( Thanks.

Comment: Win32 isn't the funnest API to use :-P

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the productName+version that marketing uses, it's in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Product Name

Looking at my computer, it says "Windows 8.1 Pro".

Answer (score 1):

and also have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/winver_macros.aspx

Answer (score 0):

And here's an example from something I came across recently:

```
OSVERSIONINFO osvi;

ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);

GetVersionEx(&osvi);
// use osvi.dwMajorVersion and osvi.dwMinorVersion
```

You'll need to run some tests to check which versions of windows the numbers correspond to.  this might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Windows#Windows_NT

```
// (bad) example to check if we're running Windows XP
if (osvi.dwMajorVersion == 5 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 1)
{
    // Windows XP
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a link to a related .NET question and set of answers.  The C++/Win32 answer is essentially the same after some trivial mapping between .NET and C++/Win32.

[How to translate MS Windows OS version numbers into product names in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545666/how-to-translate-ms-windows-os-version-numbers-into-product-names-in-net)