# How can I detect what OS the user is running?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-7

I am using VB .Net 2.0. I know I can detect the OS using

```
System.Environment.OSVersion
```

Can anyone tell me if there's a list somewhere where I can find what that generates for different OS versions.

Specifically I am trying to detect if a user is running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860459/determine-os-using-the-environment-osversion-object-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a list of versions see here: http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/08/17/windows-os-version-numbers/

To find out 32 vs 64 bit, see this previous question: [How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Answer (score 1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5956c04f-072a-406c-ae6a-cc8b3a207936

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Environment.OSVersion.ToString()
```

This will return values like:

```
"Microsoft Windows NT 5.0.2195.0"
```

[Here is a link](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_os_version.html) on how to extract the OS from the version/build numbers.

Or you can [use this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545666/how-to-translate-ms-windows-os-version-numbers-into-product-names-in-net):

```
Public Function GetOSVersion() As String
    Select Case Environment.OSVersion.Platform
        Case PlatformID.Win32S
            Return "Win 3.1"
        Case PlatformID.Win32Windows
            Select Case Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
                Case 0
                    Return "Win95"
                Case 10
                    Return "Win98"
                Case 90
                    Return "WinME"
                Case Else
                    Return "Unknown"
            End Select
        Case PlatformID.Win32NT
            Select Case Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major
                Case 3
                    Return "NT 3.51"
                Case 4
                    Return "NT 4.0"
                Case 5
                    Select Case _
                        Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
                        Case 0
                            Return "Win2000"
                        Case 1
                            Return "WinXP"
                        Case 2
                            Return "Win2003"
                    End Select
                Case 6
                    Return "Vista/Win2008Server"
                Case Else
                    Return "Unknown"
            End Select
        Case PlatformID.WinCE
            Return "Win CE"
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The most comprehensive solution for this I've found is PJ Naughter's [DtWinver](http://www.naughter.com/dtwinver.html) class. It can distinguish between editions of Windows (Starter Edition, Home Basic, Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, etc.), which admittedly might be functionality you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, Instead of checking the version numbers , this just checks the text that is returned by the Windows OS

GET the OPERATING SYSTEM NAME

```
        Dim machineOSPlatform as String
        If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("7") Then
            machineOSPlatform = "Windows 7"
        ElseIf My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("XP") Then
            machineOSPlatform = "Windows XP"
        ElseIf My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("8") Then
            machineOSPlatform = "Windows 8"
        ElseIf My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Vista") Then
            machineOSPlatform = "Windows Vista"
        ElseIf My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("2008") Then
            machineOSPlatform = "Windows 2008 Server"
        ElseIf My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("2012") Then
            machineOSPlatform = "Windows 2012 Server"
        ElseIf My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("2003") Then
            machineOSPlatform - "Windows 2003 Server"
        Else
            machineOSPlatform = "Unknown OS"
        End If
```

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?676340-how-can-i-get-visual-basic-to-show-what-os-your-running