# How do I know my website is hosting in IIS6 or IIS7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, iis-6

My ASP.NET MVC site needs to be running in either IIS6 or IIS7, I need to a url with a suffix of ".mvc" when its running in IIS6.

I know I could add an AppSetting but is there away to know if the site is running in IIS6(IIS7 classic mode) or IIS7?

Comment: You mean detect it from code or just find out which IIS you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **do not** need to have an extension for MVC on IIS **unless** you are using MVC1. MVC2 and up work just fine with extensionless URLs on IIS6.

However, to answer your question, check out this previous question: [How to detect IIS version using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446390/how-to-detect-iis-version-using-c)

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I dont find a way to let my MVC2 website works on IIS6 with extensionless,do you have the solution?

Comment: It should "just work." Is your server up-to-date? As long as you have .NET 4+ it shouldn't need anything else. We have a dev server with Server 2003/IIS 6 and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks again,I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the http response header from the client side with a browser developer tool (F12).